# Use Summernote with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, summernote

I'm trying to get Summernote working with Webpack, but somehow it does not work.

I installed summernote with yarn `yarn add summernote`.

In my javascript file I'm importing webpack:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'summernote/dist/summernote';

$('#summernote').summernote({});
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()(...).summernote is not a function
```

If I use the summernote js from the dist folder, I also get this error on my webpack console (I don't have this error when importing summernote.js from the src directory (`import 'summernote/src/js/summernote.js'`)):

```
warning  in ./node_modules/jQuery/dist/jquery.js

There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* /path/to/node_modules/jQuery/dist/jquery.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    /path/to/node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.js
* /path/to/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
    Used by 534 module(s), i. e.
    /path/to/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--4-0!/path/to/assets/js/app.js
```

I tried this: [enter link description here](https://github.com/summernote/summernote-webpack-example), but same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem

I think the issue here is to `require` the wrong `jquery` package name when the repo has been built with `webpack`. I did have a look at the built code and here is `jquery` required:

```js
module.exports = factory(require("jQuery")); // this should be `jquery` instead
```

Also there's a ticket raised but it seems nothing got fixed.

#### Solution

Luckily `webpack` allows us to define how a module is resolved by listing the module in `resolve.alias` as following:

```js
// webpack.config.js

const path from "path";

module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // resolve `jQuery` with actual `jquery` module
      jQuery: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery"),
    },
  },
  // ...
};
```

PS: Based on your comment which is using Symfony you can modify and add an alias to `jQuery` like this:

```js
// fetch the config, then modify it!
const config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

// Add another alias to jQuery
config.resolve.alias.jQuery = path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery")

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: I'm using webpack encore in combination with Symfony. This has already this in the config file `module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();`. So I think I need to add something to the config another way?

Comment: Just override the config as addressed here https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/advanced-config.html.

Comment: I also dropped an idea for you as part of answer now

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Did it this way: `Encore.addAliases({
    jQuery: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery"),
});`

Comment: Cool. Seems to be so. If it really works, please don't forget to accept the answer ;)